# Spawn process to different python environment

Tags: python

I'm using an application which uses it's own python interpreter.
When I spawn a new process:

```
subprocess.Popen(["xdg-open", folder])
```

in this application the new process still uses the applications python.

How can I spawn it so it uses the systems python?

Comment: Specify the path.  `subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python','script.py',...])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I not quite get it.
 `subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python3', "xdg-open", folder]) `

Comment: the problem is, that I need it to be done in one script.
So spawning from a seperate script.py like you suggested is not a solution to me.

Comment: What you're saying makes no sense.  If you're trying to launch a script, then you have to call Python.  If you're not trying to launch a script, then why does the Python version matter?  What is `folder`, exactly?  Show us your code. Don't make us guess.

Comment: folder variable is the path to a folder. xdg-open will just open the default filebrowser at the given location.
The problem is, that the filebrowser is using the wrong python interpreter.

Comment: Your file browser doesn't use Python.  How does Python get involved there?